# Cannot create In App Purchase in google play developer console

Tags: in-app-purchase, product, google-play-console

In the google play console inside an App if I go to

Monetise > in-app products > Create product

I did put in the Product ID, the Name and the Description.

If I click on Set price I am able to set the price, but under Local prices I can only see a LoadingIndicator.

[image: Monetise > in-app products > Create Product > Set price > Local prices]

I am able to set the price, but when I hit save it tells me 'Some prices have errors', Your changes couldn't be saved

[image: Monetise > in-app products > Create Product > Save]

I also get the Error:

```
An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again. (56C058BC)
```

Is there something I am missing?
Or how can I create a product in the google play console?

Comment: hey friend, how you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the same issue the only way to solve it is to create a new developer account and transfer your app.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Happened to me as well, clicking on "Update exchange rates" solved it, for some reason some of the prices were outdated (old/missing exchange rates and tax rates)

Comment: This should be the answer! Just "Update exchange rates", link the pricing template to your project and then edit the prices.